# Convert a character in the form of DD-MMM-YY to DD/MM/YY in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset I am working on which has dates in the form of DD-MMM-YY i.e. 1st January 2015 is represented as 01-Jan-15. I would like to convert these dates into the form DD/MM/YY i.e. 01/01/15 in R. I have tried using the as.date function but I am not able to do so. 
Help in any form will be appreciated.

Comment: There is a lot of questions here regarding this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+convert+character+to+date

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `strptime` and `format`:

Here's `strptime`:

```
x <- "01-Jan-15"
strptime(x, format = "%d-%b-%y")
# [1] "2015-01-01 IST"
```

Now, wrap it in `format`:

```
format(strptime(x, format = "%d-%b-%y"), "%d/%m/%y")
# [1] "01/01/15"
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. All I had to do next was use as.date to convert it into an object of class Date.

Comment: Does it depend on any local settings whether this works? Your first strptime returns `NA` for me. (Using your code)

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid, yes. Several parts of "format" in `strptime` are locale dependent (like `%b`, `%B`, and so on).

Comment: i dont know why but %y in strptime increases year by 1. replacing it with %Y works fine.

Comment: @user1859050 that is because the `%y` works for year in a format where you would have `19` representing the year `2019`, but if you are trying to work with a year written as `2019`, then you need to use `%Y`. It's actually written in the documentation :)